# how to auto close quotes like vscode in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I have a textarea, and I want to quote repeat in javascript.

`<textarea><!-- user types some h1's, and other tags and types a quote. --></textarea>`

But, when it types a quote once I need it to repeat.
I've tried using [`str.repeat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_repeat.asp),

but I can only put quotes at the end using the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a more accurate answer need to show what you try (some JavaScript), but i think you need to use str.repeat in placeholder like:

```
let chorus = 'Because I\'m happy.';

console.log(`Chorus lyrics for "Happy": "${chorus.repeat(1)}"`);
```

Edit:
To approximate the effect as in vs-code, you can try something like this:

```
<textarea id="textArea" name="textAreaName" rows="5" cols="50">
 Try to add quote
</textarea>

<script>
    let textArea = document.querySelector('#textArea');
    textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){
    let position = this.selectionStart;
       if (ev.keyCode == 222 ) {
           let value = ev.target.value; 
            ev.target.value =  [value.slice(0, position), ev.key, value.slice(position)].join('')
            ev.target.selectionEnd = position;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Disclaimer: This not work for in case of nested quotes!

Comment: I edit my answer with disclaimer (not work for in case of nested quotes). If you need/want help or advice you have to provide more information and what you tried to solve the problem (with some code). I hope this will help you or show the way to solve the task.

Comment: You can check the new update. Delegation of task is not so productive. Advice - try to accurate specify what you want and then you will see that you can do it or find it easy. Good luck with all you do!